# How to add a custom button in Leaflet.js layer control?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using Leaflet.js built-in Control Layers function to create the panel on the map, which allows you to toggle layers on and off from view.

I would also like to be able to have a button next to each layer toggle, which when clicked on zooms the user into that feature (layer bounds) on the map.

The hint in the Leaflet.js docs that shows how to put HTML into the label isn’t working for a button, the button is created but the on click events don’t work for it.

This seems to be because it’s grouped with the checkbox input. Has anyone come across this problem before and has a solution?